# What are these services created when i install oracle?

Tags: oracle, installation, oracle10g, oracle11g, oracle9i

I have installed oracle in my system i see different services created can some one describe a little about these. or a source where i can found some description.

```
oracle INNOVATEST VSS Writer Service

OracleDBConsoleInnovaTest

OracleJobSchedulerINNOVATEST

OracleOraDb11g_home1TNSListener

OracleOraDb11g_home1ConfigurationMangager

OracleServiceINNOVATEST
```

Comment: Just wondering. Are you using version 11? How do you like it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found some documentation for you.

I'd suggest you poke around on Oracle's Documentation page found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11857_01/index.htm)

[oracle INNOVATEST VSS Writer Service](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/install.111/b32006/whatsnew.htm#CEGHIGGC)

[OracleJobSchedulerINNOVATEST](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/scheduse.htm)

[OracleOraDb11g_home1TNSListener](http://docs.oracle.com/html/B13738_01/ch5.htm#i25111)

[OracleOraDb11g_home1ConfigurationMangager](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28601_01/doc.1037/e26168/ccrqs.htm)